# How can I do a wget with parameters in NiFi

Tags: get, apache-nifi, wget, jython

I'm trying to consult an API with NiFi, parameters which comes from a database, so I need to use attributes as part of the URL.

I cannot use GetHttp, because it doesn't accept attributes. I've tried to use ExecuteScript, using Jython, I have some troubles...

```
import json
import java.lang.Exception
from urllib import urlopen
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback

# Define a subclass of InputStreamCallback for use in session.read()
class PyInputStreamCallback(StreamCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process(self,inputStream,outputStream):
        text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        data_old = json.loads(text)
        data_new = {}
        for data in data_old:
            # Prepare key
            ip = data_old.get('keys')[0].get('ip')
            
            data_ok = urlopen('http://'+ip+'/api/data?begintime=2021-09-30T23:59:59.000+02:00')
        
        #data_ok = list(data_new.values())
        
        outputStream.write(bytearray(json.dumps(data_ok).encode("utf-8")))

flowFile = session.get()
if (flowFile != None):
    try:
        flowFile = session.write(flowFile,PyInputStreamCallback())
        session.transfer(flowFile,REL_SUCCESS)
    except java.lang.Exception as err:
        log.error("Something went wrong", err)
        session.transfer(flowFile,REL_FAILURE)
```

It shows me

> ScriptException: TypeError: <addinfourl at 2764827 whose fp = <_socket._fileobject object at 0x2a301c>> is not JSON serializable in  at line number 30

Line number 30 it not important, because it only says the error is in the write function, which uses PyInputStreamCallback.process

I've tried to use python's requests library, but it is not in Jython...

Does anybody fight with this trouble before?

Comment: what is your ‘text’ . is it valid json string

Comment: Yes, I don't have problems with Text. I even take 'ip' field correctly (for a moment, I forgot 'keys' was an array, and it complains about it, hehe).

Answer (score 0):

While GetHTTP may not take attributes, [InvokeHTTP](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.15.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/) does. GetHTTP is largely deprecated, so you should evaluate InvokeHTTP for your needs, as this sounds like a good fit and you can avoid custom scripting.